# What's this spring-like structure in the plant parenchyma cell?

Tags: botany, plant-anatomy, species-identification

I observed a transverse section of an amaranth stem in biology lesson today. When I boost the magnification to 600X, I found this spring-like structure in one of the parenchyma cells near a vascular bundle. I could only find one of these in the section. Can anyone tell what structure is it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a part of a xylem cell (particularly vessel). Take a look at pics in [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xylem). Another good example is [here](http://www.microscopy-uk.org.uk/mag/indexmag.html?http://www.microscopy-uk.org.uk/mag/artaug04/wdaptenia.html) on pic. 36. Possibly you have dragged a part of it during cutting. So it is presumably not a part of parenchyma cell.

Comment: I came here to ask the same question. Thanks for the answer and links!